# How to set count to a PagingButton in SAP ui5

Tags: sapui5

**XML**

```
<PagingButton positionChange="pagination" position="1" count="5" id="pagingBtn" nextButtonTooltip="next" previousButtonTooltip="previous"/>
```

Instead of count="5", From controller I have to set count of paging button. How to set count from controller..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.byId("pagingBtn").setProperty("count", 10);
```

and delete the count attribute from the xml